# zsh:1: command not found: pip in jupyterlab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I install `Jupyter`  by following `https://jupyter.org/install`

```
pip install jupyterlab

jupyter-lab
```

but when I open the file and try to run

```
!pip install opencv-python
```

I get

```
zsh:1: command not found: pip
```

Is my installation process wrong?

Comment: try !pip3 install opencv-python

Comment: that works, thanks